# Как правильно настроить PHPDoc?

Tags: php, phpdoc

Имеется проект на Yii1. PSR-4 не используется.
После генерации документации в шаблоне `clean` появляются ссылки на классы. Если в двух разных папках лежит класс с одинаковым именем, то в меню выведутся две ссылки, но они будут одинаковыми, соответственно, я могу посмотреть документацию только по одному классу.
Как заставить phpdoc генерировать уникальную ссылку для каждого класса?

Comment: Добавил @package, результата нет

Comment: Нашел в коде PHPDocumentator место, где генерируется URL. Для элементов с типом `Class` добавил к URL `package`, в URL теперь добавляется название пакета (`/classes/Default/ClassName.html`), но при наличии нескольких классов, последний 404. Однако, в папке данных этот класс есть. Получается, он не рендерится.

Comment: Мысль вслух (так как ни с Yii, ни с phpdoc дел особых не имел). А нельзя там в качестве префикса `namespace` использовать? В том смысле, чтоб fully qualified имя класса использовать

Comment: @rjhdby Для Yii2 с этим проблем нет, а вот в Yii1 префиксы вместо неймспейсов. А в проекте, для которого я пытаюсь сгенерировать документацию, с этим вообще все плохо. Ни префиксов, ни неймспесов. Только `@package` остается...